# clevertap Deeplink notification is redirecting to safari instead of mobile app when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, clevertap

clevertap Deeplink notification is redirecting to safari instead of mobile app when app is in background ,

Can any one help on me on this

Comment: if app is not in background then working fine?

Comment: Yes , if the app is not in background its working fine

Comment: @Nayeem Have you found solution/reason for this? For me it happens in Foreground and Background both cases

Comment: What is the structure of the deeplink you are using?

Comment: hey @Nayeem did you find the solution for this? As we are facing the same issue it would be great help if you answer this post

Comment: in deeplink we need to pass some different key not default key

Comment: I am also facing same if anybody can help

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to understand why your Deeplink is opening in the browser first and then redirecting you to the Application

> If a deep link starts with HTTPS on iOS devices, the default behavior
> is to open that link in the browser. If you have implemented a
> universal link, safari will show you a banner at the top asking if you
> want to open it in the app.

You can read about it more here:-
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

> If you would like to open the app directly from the push notification
> using an HTTPS link, you should not include the URL in the deep link
> input field. You can instead pass the HTTPS: deep link as a custom
> key-value pair, then In you app you can read the custom key-value pair
> and decide the redirection logic, or if you don't wanna pass URL, you can also  pass an identifier which needs to be handled in your app.

Please check this image for more Information:

[image: Please check this image for more Information]